# How to replace entire StringBuilder value?

Tags: c#, stringbuilder

I need to assign a new string value to completely replace the existing string value in a `StringBuilder` object.

But,

`sb.Append()` will only add to the **end** of a string, and `sb.Insert(0,stringVal)` will only add to the **beginning** of the string.

`sb.Replace()` will replace **PART** of the string, IF I know what part of it is to look for it.

I simply need to just replace the entire `sb` string value with a new value even though I do not know what the current contents of the string is.

Comment: And you can't just use `Clear()`?

Comment: ... or `sb = new StringBuilder();` ?

Comment: @Dave, if you will make that an answer, I will mark it accepted.

Comment: @KWallace I don't seem to be able to respond to your comment without the comment being deleted, it would be nice to know why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sb.Clear()` removes all characters from the current StringBuilder instance.

Answer (score 2):

```
sb.Clear();
sb.Append("new string");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can always replace any instance by recreating it.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.Append("something");
sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.Append("replaced");
```